# Removing # in AngularJS App and refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am working on Leshan lightweight M2M server. The app loads on java jar.There is a requirement to remove # from the URL. After going through a lot of pages I got to the following changes:

- index.html:

  ```
  <base href="/">
  ```

  in head
- app.js :

  ```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  ```

But when refreshing the page i get HTTP Error 404- Not found.  There are solutions given for tomcat and express server but iam unable to find anything for Java Jar. How can i make this work on page refresh?

Comment: Try this: `app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);`

Comment: tried this too..but its not working when refreshing the page

Comment: You need to add a default binding for `/*` in Leshan server, which serves your root file (typically `index.html`).

Comment: When you are refreshing it's asking for a new resource, instead of re-directing from previous (base) resource. You have to edit you **htaccess** re-route rules for that to work, since AngularJS doesn't handle that. It should be located at the root of the server. Try appending these rules: `RewriteEngine on` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`

Comment: @FrontEndDeveloper I personally don't know, but this is for sure beyond the scope of this question, try to make a new one with appropriate tags

Comment: Fixed this issye by changing a java file from which the webapp was loading, edited the context path from there.